# How to load viewModel on the startDestination fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel

I am trying to make an app which displays a list of data on the first fragment shown when the app is loaded.

I am using navigation component and I instantiate the viewmodel in the MainActivity

*EventViewModel.kt*

```
...
    val events: MutableLiveData<Resource<List<Event>>> = MutableLiveData()

    init {
        getEvents()
    }

    private fun getEvents() = viewModelScope.launch {
        events.postValue(Resource.Loading())
        val response = eventRepository.getEvents(load())
        events.postValue(handleGetEvents(response))
    }
...
```

*ActivityMain.kt*

```kotlin
...
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // Bind binding to xml
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        // Setup viewModel dependency injection
        val eventRepository = EventRepository(EventDatabase(this))
        val eventViewModelProviderFactory = EventViewModelProviderFactory(eventRepository)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, eventViewModelProviderFactory).get(EventViewModel::class.java)


        // Setup nav
        bottomBar = binding.bottomNavigationView
        navController = findNavController( R.id.fragment)
        bottomBar.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }
 ...
```

The FirstFragment shown is loading the viewModel from Main activity inside onViewCreated like this:

*FragmentFirst.kt*

```kotlin
...
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = (activity as MainActivity).viewModel
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(view);

        viewModel.events.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { response ->
            when(response) {
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    response.data?.let {
                        initRecyclerView(it)
                        initViewPager(it)
                    }
                }
                is Resource.Error -> {
                    response.message?.let {
                        println("Error occured: $it")
                    }
                }
            }

        })
    }
...
```

And then I get this error

```
Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property viewModel has not been initialized
```

I know the reason is that the viewmodel takes time to instantiate, because it is calling the internet and receiving data, for the LiveData, Because I tested it by putting another Fragment as the StartDestination, containing a button to navigate to the FragmentFirst, and then it worked fine.

I guess I could wrap the whole viewModel with an observer pattern and make the fragment observe on the instantiation of the viewModel. But I think the viewModel should already have some feature or something which doesn't require me to do that.

So my question is::: Is it possible to have the viewmodel observers as the first fragment loading in the app, and how can I do it, if it is?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It can’t be because your ViewModel takes a long time to instantiate because it is instantiated on the main thread, which the fragment’s `onViewCreated` is also called on. (And if you are using a blocking call during instantiation of the ViewModel, that could trigger an ANR, so don’t do that.) The problem probably is your execution order. Please show the entire onCreate of your activity.

Comment: Yes thanks, It is updated now

Comment: We tried removing the initblock from the viewmodel and it is still not working

Comment: Yes, that's what I was saying. There's no way a long-instantiation time could cause this issue because the ViewModel is instantiated on the main thread. I can't find a problem in the code you've posted. Note that you can get a reference to the same view model in the Fragment by passing the Activity rather than the Fragment to the ViewModelProvider constructor.